# On key event for python

Tags: python, keypress

I was having trouble trying to find a python solution to on keypress event, this allows you add a event handler to a keypress and passes that handler the current string until a newline

```
import msvcrt, sys

def get_string( on_key=False ):
    string = []
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            char = msvcrt.getch()
            string.append( char )
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            if on_key:
                on_key( ''.join( string ) )
            if ord(char) == 13:
                return ''.join( string )

def onkeydo( string ):
    print "So far it is: ", string

string = get_string( onkeydo )

print "Final string was ", string
```

As far as I know this is windows specific

Comment: What's the question here?  This looks more like something for ActiveState I think.

Comment: Why are you looking around `kbhit()`? If you want to block until a key is pressed, just do a blocking `getch()` call; writing it this way forces the computer to waste as much CPU time as possible, with no benefits.